# Problems with using sklearm.preprocessing.PowerTransformer() before splitting data using train_test_split

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

Since my data are not normally distributed so I decided to use PowerTransformer on X, y before splitting them to X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test. Is it okay if I do this or I should perform transformation later. Here is my code:

```
X = df[['Aces', 'TotalPointsWon', 'ServiceGamesWon', 'TotalServicePointsWon']]
y = df[['Winnings']]

transformer_X = PowerTransformer()
X_log = transformer_X.fit_transform(X)

transformer_y = PowerTransformer()
y_log = transformer_y.fit_transform(y)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_log, y_log, train_size=0.8)

scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
scaler.transform(X_test)

model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

[Residuals Analyses Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6dER.png)

Thanks for helping out.

Comment: I don't think that for linear regression the underlying data have to be normally distributed.

Comment: @pavel but if my data is skewed, the model will be trained disproportionately on a larger number of lower values. As a result, it would fail the residuals analysis. Isn't that correct? I'm not sure.

Comment: No, it shouldn't make a difference. Linear regression only assumes that residuals are normally distributed (which is almost a given if data follow a somewhat linear trend). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares#Assumptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PowerTransformer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PowerTransformer.html) makes data more Gaussian-like, feature-wise.

Just like any data preprocessing step, the rule of thumb is to **fit** (i.e learn the parameters) the training data, then **transform** both the latter and the test set (i.e applying the learned parameters to the unseen new data).

Hence, the **fit** method should only be applied to the training data, with the assumption that it represents the statistical distribution of whole sample (i.e. make sure to use stratified splits if it is a classification problem, and make sure you have enough examples, use cross validation, ...etc).

---

### Why?

Because at some time, you'll receive new unseen data that you'll have **only** to *transform*. That's why you're splitting the data at the stage, to simulate this event and validate that the model is not overfitting nor underfitting and did actually learn how to represent the data.

Otherwise, your model would be biased, and [data snooping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_dredging) will be, to a certain degree, applicable here.

---

### Final words

Please note that `PowerTransformer` accepts a parameter called `method` that specifies one of the two available power transform methods:

1. `yeo-johnson`: which works with positive and negative values.
2. `box-cox`: which only works with strictly positive values.

You can read more about them [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2673623) and [here](https://www.ime.usp.br/%7Eabe/lista/pdfQWaCMboK68.pdf), respectively.

Comment: So it means that I should split first and then `fit_transform` the X_train, y_train. Then, `transform` the X_test, y_test. Is that correct?

Comment: @BreyeNguyen Yes, exactly. And that's a rule for almost all preprocessing steps (I know no exception to this).

Comment: thanks a lot. However, now the assumptions of Linear Regression are not met anymore. Can you help me with that? Much appreciated.